# Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous such that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=0.$ Show that there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $\int_{0}^{c}xf(x)dx=0.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=0.$$ Prove that there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $$\int_{0}^{c}xf(x)dx=0.$$

I guess that it is necessary some version of the Mean Value Theorem to prove this statement.

If $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$, we know by the Rolle's Theorem that $F'(\alpha)=f(\alpha)=0$ for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$. However, I have not found any interesting use for this $\alpha$.

If $G(x)=\int_{0}^{x}tf(t)dt$, we have to prove that $G(c)=0$ for some $c\in (0,1)$. If we assume that it is false, we have by the Intermediate Value Theorem that either $G(x)>0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$ or $G(x)<0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.

Would you give me some ideas to complete the proof?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrals conditioning relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150711/integrals-conditioning-relations)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/34808/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2314705/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3997204/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Bc%7Dxf(x)dx%3D0.%24)

Comment: Here is a nice *direct* proof using the mean-value theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35200/42969